# Getting an error when using arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint()

Tags: arcpy

I get this error when I run my script:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 15, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'XYTableToPoint'

Script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'U:\skelley\Python\Outputs'
inTable = r'U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\FWD_Halsey_WGS1984.csv'
arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(inTable, "quasars", "lat", "long", 
arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  I'm guessing you're in 10.x and using a Pro tool based on Google search. The similar tool for Desktop is [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm).

Comment: Using Desktop Advanced - documentation says that this tool is available with this license. We've used it manually before; I'm just trying to simplify a process by writing some code.

Comment: Could you please post a link to that doc? I haven't found it in my search.

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm

Comment: This is a tool that is available in ArcGIS Pro -- at check the URL of the website.  As a workaround, use the Desktop geoprocessing tool called Make XY Event Layer.

Comment: Got it, thanks. The licensing section at the bottom threw me - I figured since we could use the tool, we'd be able to use the function. Hm.

But I'll give that other function a try, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. (I agree, the licensing wording is confusing!) I've posted this and more detail as an answer. If this works for you, please remember to marks it as accepted so that others know the question is resolved.

Comment: One more question - XY Event Layer was created, but is displaying no data. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have items in the attribute table but nothing in your display? Double-check that you have a spatial reference assigned.

Comment: Yes, items in the attribute table and nothing in the display. Spatial reference has been assigned...maybe there's something wrong with the reference code I used. I'll look into it.

Comment: Ok, you may want to post as separate question with your code snippet to get more focused response.

Comment: Another common cause is that latlong are reversed. Remember lat maps to Y and long maps to X.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. Switched lat and long, worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [Why is Python Script (using XYTabletoPoint) Deleting target Feature Class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283284):

[XY Table To Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm) is a tool available in ArcGIS Pro. A search online for "XY Table To Point arcpy 10.3" does not return any documentation for 10.x, but does return a different tool, [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm). Note when using the Desktop tool Make XY Event Layer that it creates a layer, not a point feature class or shapefile. To save the output after the event layer is created, use [arcpy.management.CopyFeatures](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm)

Be careful with latlong and this tool. Remember X should map to longitude, and Y to latitude, so code is for example :

```
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, "longitude" , "latitude",
    out_Layer, spRef, z_coords)
```